# 95% Completed JAVA Array Code. Can anyone help me find my error?

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

```
public class ArrayProject
{
    private int[] myArray;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int myArray[] = {2, 45, 12, 15, 16};

        System.out.println("Minimium Value:" + findMin(myArray));
        System.out.println("Maximium Value:" + findMax(myArray));
    }

    public ArrayProject(int[] x)
    {
        myArray=x;
    }

    public static int findMin(int[] myArray){
        int minValue = myArray[0];
        for(int i=1;i<myArray.length;i++){
            if(myArray[i] < minValue){
                minValue = myArray[i];
            }
        }
        return minValue;
    }

    public static int findMax(int[] myArray){
        int maxValue = myArray[0];
        for(int i=1;i<myArray.length;i++){
            if(myArray[i] > maxValue){
                maxValue = myArray[i];
            }
        }
        return maxValue;
    }

    public void swap (int minIndex, int maxIndex)
    {
        int temp;
        temp = myArray[minIndex];
        myArray[minIndex] = myArray[maxIndex];
        myArray[maxIndex] = temp;
    }

    public int findValue(int value)
    {
        for(int i=1;i<myArray.length; i++){
            System.out.println(myArray[i]);
            return myArray[i];

        }

    }

}
```

I am having an issue compiling the findValue method. The last method. Can anyone help me fix?
........................
I am confused with how you return the value as.

The class basically finds min max, and the array values.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You said you're having an issue with findValue method, what issue? What is the output you're expecting from the method & what is the output value? Please post the compile error, if any

Comment: For reference, `findValue` would always return the 1th (second) value.  This would have jumped up and winked at you if you'd just indent your code properly.

Comment: **I am confused with**   We are confused with ur question..  :-)

Comment: I think you need a if() condition before returning a value?

Comment: How did you calculate the completion percentage of your code?

Comment: @JasonC: If you're just starting, it's 50%.  Otherwise, it's 95%.  Everyone knows the last 5% is the part that takes 95% of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if no value is found? Nothing is returned, but the method expects an int. You need to return an int value for all possible scenarios in findValue().

You can add an arbitrarily impossible number (according to your expectations) like -1:

```
return -1;
```

after

```
for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
        return myArray[i];

}
```

if no values are found, since you are using primitives. If your return type is Integer instead, you can return null instead, which makes more sense. Otherwise, the method would only work for non-negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You never create an instance of `ArrayProject` so your constructor never gets called and the `myArray` member is never set.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the int in for loop.
Try declaring int variable assign value to it and return that int variable.
Or return the whole array

Answer (score 1):

Not every code path in your `findValue()` function returns a value. You need to add a `return` statement outside of the `for` loop. This is necessary because the `for` loop may or may not always execute, depending on the length of `myArray`. If the `for` loop does not execute, then a function that you have declared to return and `int` will not execute any return statement, which is not allowed by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this .

```
int[] nums={2, 45, 12, 15, 16};  
Arrays.sort(nums);  
System.out.println("Minimum = " + nums[0]);  
System.out.println("Maximum = " + nums[nums.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic fix for your problem, since your return statement was in the for-loop and is may not always run.

```
public int findValue(int value)
{
    int returnValue = -1;
    for(int i=1;i<myArray.length; i++){
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
        returnValue = myArray[i];

    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Not a good fix, but it compiles.

Also if the function need to find a value, you need to add an if-statement to check if the searched value matches the number in the array position

```
public int findValue(int value)
{
    int returnValue = -1;
    for(int i=1;i<myArray.length; i++){
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
        if(value == myArray[i]){
            returnValue = myArray[i];
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

-1 is if the element was not found.